# TextBox enable/disable by radiobutton in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, radio-button

i have 4 Radio buttons in Winform and one of radio button(radiobutton_4) is trigger to enable the Textbox which is works well. but if change any other radiobutton after checked the trigger radiobutton the textbox will not change disable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76C8E.png)

trigger radiobutton

```
    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Radioctrlvalue = "fromvalue";
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
        textBox2.Enabled = true;
        textBox3.Enabled = true;
    }
```

other radiobutton

```
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // if projectbase point radio is checked and string variable store 
      Radioctrlvalue = "projectpoint";
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
        textBox3.Enabled = false;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcQxH.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `textBox1` .. `textBox3` should be *disabled* if and only if `radioButton1.Checked` you can just assign `!radioButton1.Checked`:

```
// When radioButton1 ("Project BasePoint") Check state changed 
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = !radioButton1.Checked;
    // textBox2 and textBox3 have the same behavior
    textBox2.Enabled = textBox1.Enabled;
    textBox3.Enabled = textBox1.Enabled;
}
```

In general case (when, say, `textBox1.Enabled` should be `true` if and only if `radioButton4` or `radioButton5` are `Checked`) you can *extract a method*:

```
private void UpdateEnabled() {
  textBox1.Enabled = radioButton4.Checked || radioButton5.Checked;
  textBox2.Enabled = textBox1.Enabled;
  textBox3.Enabled = textBox1.Enabled;
  
  //TODO: Put all the other rules here
}

...

private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Radioctrlvalue = "fromvalue";
 
  UpdateEnabled();
}

private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //TODO: Relevant code here
 
  UpdateEnabled();
}
```

Comment: thanks Dmitry, but i want disable the TextBox. can you Please check the image I have added.

Comment: @Thiruvarasan Kaliyaperumal: as far as I can see, all the `TextBox`es should be *disabled* if and only if `radioButton1.Checked`. If it's your case you can try `CheckedChanged` event of `radioButton1`. Please, see my edit

Comment: thanks, it is work but i have changed it AND operation.textBox1.Enabled = !radioButton1.Checked && !radioButton2.Checked && !radioButton3.Checked;

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you change radiobuttons state all attached to each radiobutton CheckedChanged functions are executing, even if state changes to false. You should check state in function and execute your code only if state is "checked".

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as radioButton).Checked)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }     
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as radioButton).Checked)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    }     
}
```

You can even use only ONE function attached to all radioButtons handling with all variants. For example set RadioButton1.Tag value to false, RadioButton2.Tag value to true and use it in code.

```
private void AllRadioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as radioButton).Checked)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = (bool)((sender as radioButton).Tag);
    }     
}
```